# Flask App 404 on subdirectory

Tags: apache, flask

I'm trying to have flask run on `http://<my-server.com>/UserControl`

Here are the relevant files:

**Apache**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
    ServerName <redacted>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    # not needed actually because we're proxying everything to Tomcat, but just leave it to make Apache happy
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    DirectoryIndex index.php


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  <Location /alpha>
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Restricted Access - Authenticate"
     AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/htpasswd.users
     Require valid-user
   </Location>

   <Location /UserControl>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Access - Authenticate"
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/htpasswd.users
        Require valid-user
   </Location>

  Redirect /alpha /alpha/
  ProxyPass /alpha/ http://127.0.0.1:3838/alpha/
  ProxyPassReverse /alpha/ http://127.0.0.1:3838/alpha/


  WSGIDaemonProcess UserControl user=ubuntu group=ubuntu threads=5
  WSGIScriptAlias /UserControl/ /home/ubuntu/FlaskApps/UserControl/UserControl.wsgi

  <Directory /home/ubuntu/FlaskApps/UserControl>
            WSGIProcessGroup UserControl
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            WSGIScriptReloading On
            Order deny,allow
            #Allow from all
            Require all Granted
   </Directory>



</VirtualHost>
```

Note that I have some other directories that I run things on.

My relevant .py and .wsgi files are:

**UserControl.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/UserControl")
def main():
    return "Welcome!"

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**UserControl.wsgi**

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert (0,'/home/ubuntu/FlaskApps/UserControl')
#os.chdir("/home/ubuntu/FlaskApps")
from UserControl import app as application
```

The files are located in

```
/home/ubuntu/FlaskApps/UserControl
```

However when I access:

`http://<my-server.com/>UserControl` I get a 404 (by FLASK! -- so apache seems to route correctly)

What exactly am I missing?

Comment: Do you have debugging turned on?  Any error reports from Flask?

Comment: I have exactly this problem...I am kind of surprised this is not a more popular topic.  What was your solution, @user1357015 ?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the route without using a trailing slash. Your reverse proxy is likely redirecting to the route *with* the slash. When you define a route this way, accessing the URL with a trailing slash will produce a 404 “Not Found” error. This is covered in the [quickstart guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#variable-rules).

You can either disable 'strict slashes' or define the route with the trailing slash.

From the documentation:

> Take these two rules:

```
@app.route('/projects/')
def projects():
    return 'The project page'

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return 'The about page'
```

> Though they look rather similar, they differ in their use of the trailing slash in the URL definition. In the first case, the canonical URL for the projects endpoint has a trailing slash. In that sense, it is similar to a folder on a filesystem. Accessing it without a trailing slash will cause Flask to redirect to the canonical URL with the trailing slash.
>
> In the second case, however, the URL is defined without a trailing slash, rather like the pathname of a file on UNIX-like systems. Accessing the URL with a trailing slash will produce a 404 “Not Found” error.
>
> This behavior allows relative URLs to continue working even if the trailing slash is omitted, consistent with how Apache and other servers work. Also, the URLs will stay unique, which helps search engines avoid indexing the same page twice.

Comment: I've changed it to @app.route("/UserControl/") and I still get a not fond.

Comment: Try logging the requests to a file or look at the debug output. You should see something like `127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017 12:24:31] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -` that will tell you what route was requested that resulted in the 404. Please verify what route the Flask app is seeing.

Comment: Where is the debug output? I'm new to flask...I can show you the apache request? `<ip REDACTED> - demo [30/Jan/2017:22:00:40 +0000] "GET /UserControl/ HTTP/1.1" 404 429 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"`

Comment: Did you restart apache after changing your code? Your message seems to indicate the behavior I described in my answer.